# How to prepare for 10k run with 40-42min timing

Tags: running, long-distance-running

I did my first 10k with 59.34min recently one month back.

Right now, I'm running 5 day a week.Wed and Sunday are rest day.

Last week 20Mile(32Km)

Tread Mill
Monday    6Km 9.4Km/hour 39
Tuesday   6Km 9.7Km/hour 37.24
Wednesday Rest
Thursday 6Km 10Km/hour 36.30
Friday    6Km 10.5Km/hour 35

Outdoor
Saturday  8.1 5:49/KM(pace) Time 47min (used strava)
Sunday    Rest

This Week 25Mile(40Km)

Tread Mill
Monday    7Km 10.6Km/hour 39
Today     7Km 8.9Km/hour  48
Wednesday Rest
Thursday  7Km ?
Friday    7Km ?

Outdoor
Saturday  12Km ?
Sunday    Rest

Going to add 5mile each week till 50mile/week mileage.

Today I reduced my speed after seeing lot of people injured themselves
by pushing hard and I was doing the same thing in treadmill.
I want to build mileage with my run then I want to increase my speed. I am targeting 40-43min 10k right now.

Please suggest at what pace(speed) I should run to avoid injury and build my stamina and endurance. And how should I achieve my target time without injury

Rest/Recovery plan? if any

Comment: I think this is a good question, but remember that our bodies are all different, so there is no fixed plan that will work for everyone. Injuries will usually announce themselves in good time though. You need to feel it out.

Comment: @alec i feel different after every run some times in calf or other time hamstring or shin. Some times immediately or some time after 6 hours

Comment: I can't really diagnose "different". Is it pain? Is it DOMS? Is it in the muscle? In the bone? In a joint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you've just started running? Since this is your first 10k ever.

As you've noted - an injury is imminent. And as people in the comments have said - every person's body is different.

You are increasing your mileage very steeply and rapidly which is the bigger concern, not so much as the speed. Your body will break at some point somewhere with these 5 times per week runs. Take all the hype a bit down and don't increase the week mileage by more than 15-20%.

I get what you are experiencing, which is the "runner's high" and it can give you crazy motivation but be objective about it. As a fellow runner I have made the mistake to increase rapidly the distance per week many times and this has always led back to 2-3 weeks of resting without runs because of some injury.

You can try and switch at some point from 5 training days to 3 because the body will start failing with recovery and couldn't cope with such a rapid increase in the distance. (also with the sprints, read below)

As you want to increase your speed, you need to do speed exercises and not so much mileage. You should look around the Internet for speed training programs for 5k and 10k but in general here's what you have to do:

Sprints, SPRINTS, **SPRINTS!!!**

For starters you could incorporate a 10x50m sprint after your normal runs. (you should try and run at about 80% intensity during sprinting, so that you won't die and throw up at the second sprint :D)

Warm up, I mean it! Mandatory 5 mins. warm up before the start of running. Also before starting any kind of sprint run at least 1k to kickstart that body and switch to running mode - this is after the mandatory warm up.

Some days you could skip entirely the long runs (honestly, you need just one long run per week 10-12-15km.) and after the 5 min. warm up and a 1k. run just start sprinting. You can do several types of sprints at which you'll get better over time as you progress.

Firstly try 10x600m with 3 mins. rest between sprints (during the rest you could walk and breathe, don't just stay in one place) with about 80% intensity.

Then there is the 5x1km. sprints but these are a bit more advanced and you should first do the 600m ones. Again 3 mins. rest with 80% intensity or more.

Then there are the 10x100m sprints with incline, on some hill or something and you give everything you have there, go down the hill and repeat.

Recovery after sprinting is going to be really bad, you will see. So no running on the next day.

So, let's summarize what you could do in 4 days of training per week:

- First day - Sprints
- Rest day
- Second day - Some recovery run with a convenient pace with perhaps a few increases in speed (no sprinting) for about 100m on every kilometer. About 8-10kms.
- Rest day
- Third day - Try running 5k really fast, as fast as you can, always
  warm up before that and do 1k-2k jog, then rest 1-2 mins. and start
  the 5k speed run.
- Fourth day - Long run day, slow recovery running for about 10-12km, no speed.
- Rest, Repeat

Disclaimer: *I've done all of these and you should notice increases in speed but don't get your hopes up, because it could take you from 6 months to more than a year to run the 10k for 40 mins. Also depends on your weight and your running form, shoes, injuries, etc.*

Sources: Me - Ultramarathon runner, currently will start working on my 5k speed again, because I stopped improving it last year just when I got to the 4:00/km.

Comment: I might sound silly but what should i consider my 100% intensity. Some time I run 17km/hour 20sec,15km/hour 23sec and 12Km/hour 2min

Comment: Well, 100% is usually your max heat rate. But I find it silly to run with a heart rate monitor or measure it on the clock every minute. So you should listen to your body. At 100% running effort you give your max sprinting speed and probably could last no more than 15 secs. So you have to slow down the intensity a bit and with about 80% you should be able to run significantly longer and still faster than your normal running speed. It's not a silly question but I hope I explained it enough for you to understand. If you have more questions or something isn't clear - ask away.

Comment: yeah 15 sec time what I wanted to know so i can figure out my 100% intensity. I will also make sure that i listen to my body

Answer (score 0):

To give you an idea of paces to use with @Krasimir's answer, use the Jack Daniels' Pace Calculator: https://runsmartproject.com/calculator/

Enter the results from your 10K race and then click on the training tab.

Pay close attention to the easy run pace. Going to fast on your recovery days or long days is a recipe for injury and fatigue.

Comment: Great addtition! I didn't give any paces because he has to feel what's best from the body, following what an app or a program is telling for paces may sometimes be too much tasking, as I've experienced. But that's gives the idea of what pace to use in general. :)